# In Cypress, Date and Time input fields are cleared unexpectedly after other input fields are filled

Tags: cypress, integration-testing

I have 4 input fields that must be filled to activate a form submit button.

1. Date
2. Time
3. select
4. textarea

I created a cypress test to fill each of them by order and finally click the button to submit. But cypress unexpectedly clears out the first two input fields as soon as it fills select field. I tried deleting select field but the output did not change.

[image: first two fields are cleared]

Below is my test code.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe("Home Page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.get('input[name="date"]').as("date-field");
    cy.get('input[name="time"]').as("time-field");
    cy.get('select[name="alarmMode"]').as("alarmMode-field");
    cy.get('textarea[name="content"]').as("textarea-field");
  });

  it("submits user input", () => {
    cy.get("@date-field")
      .invoke("val", "2022-04-29")
      .get("@time-field")
      .invoke("val", "12:00:00")
      .get("@alarmMode-field")
      .select("NORMAL")
      .get("@textarea-field")
      .type("hello all!!!!!");

    cy.get("form button").click();
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not reproachable from the info given. Seems likely there are event handlers causing it, but the logic isn't clear. Clicking the Submit button ***will*** clear the form (it's default HTML behaviour) but I can't tell if that step is taken in the replay. Clearly you have button `click()` in the test, but did you comment it out in the replay?

Comment: Hi. I suppose the `"val"` method in this case does not behave as normal jQuery `.val()`, so the values are not set for your input fields. Could you try `type()` your inputs and run it again?

Comment: @Fody Sorry Fody I did remove the click test code as it reproduces the error for being disabled(submit button is only enabled when 4 input fields are filled).

Comment: @AlexIzbas Awesome! I changed the two invoke methods to type and everything worked as wished. Thank you very much.